# Python jsonschema, allowing nothing, or require one and only one of two fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, jsonschema

I am working with jsonschema for Python and I am trying to allow any of the following:

```py
{}
# or
{
    'id': 'd6a4def3-4a6a-4fb4-a38e-f98ea48f708a'
}
# or
{
    'status': 'Done'
}
```

but I don't want to allow the following because both fields are provided:

```py
{
    'id': 'd6a4def3-4a6a-4fb4-a38e-f98ea48f708a',
    'status': 'Done'
}
```

This is what I have so far which allows one field or the other to be provided like I want but it doesn't allow nothing.

```py
GET_CALL = {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": False,
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": REGEX_EXPRESSIONS['UUID4'], # Matches a UUID4 format
        },
        "status": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["Done", "Ready"],
        },
    },
    "oneOf": [ # This makes it so I can only have one or the other but it doesn't allow nothing.
        {"required": ["id"]},
        {"required": ["status"]}
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your `oneOf` to cover all cases. Luckily this is not too complex.

Here's the schema you need for just what you've specified. You can work that into your existing schema.

```
{
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "id"
      ]
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "status"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

(draft-7 JSON Schema)

You can test it at [jsonschema.dev](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEB7eBTA8gM1ZIgNoLLJxJnKoCGAJnQJYAujGNANgAoBOaADph6tMYAolycwmUmQC+AGlnllZVD0wBHAK6MNdcSUpVqIRgZCrkAXVWLVFEyhAadezBcJGnpsMxrM2mKWxmS2oXKy4XIgCmZQMLKo5uKoqEqUqH4BQamWITFyQA) (link is pre-loaded with this schema and a test instance)

To clarify, you'll still need `type: object`.

Comment: Welcome! Feel free to join the JSON Schema slack should you have questions which don't belong here. We also monitor the `jsonschema` tag from here =]

Comment: Got a link to the slack?

Comment: Discuss link on http://json-schema.org - We REALLY need to make that more obvious! *adds to long long todo list*